# Get notification when tabs focus changes in MultiPageEditorPart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How can I get notified when one of the tabs is clicked in the multi page editor? IPartListener/IPartListener2 seems to react when the whole editor changes state.

Comment: Are you asking about an editor you are writing or an existing editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tabs on the multi-page editor are not Parts so they are not reported by IPartListener/IPartListener2.

`MultiPageEditorPart` does not provide an API that other parts can use to detect the tab selection. The actual editor using MultiPageEditorPart can override the `pageChange` method to be told about the tab selection.